# ¿Cómo crear desde C# una base de datos con sus tablas hacia Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Tengo este codigo para crear una base de datos desde C#, pero cuando intento crear las tablas, me dice que ya existe una tabla con ese nombre.

```
 public void CrearTablaDatosEmpresa()
        {
            using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    comando.Connection = conexion;
                    comando.CommandText = "create table TablaEmpresa (" +
                        "IdEmpresa int identity(1,1) primary key," +
                        "RucEmpresa varchar(13)," +
                        "RazonSocialEmp varchar(90)," +
                        "NombreComercialEmp varchar(90)," +
                        "TelefonoEmp1 varchar(14)," +
                        "TelefonoEmp2 varchar(14)," +
                        "CorreoEmp varchar(50)," +
                        "CiudadEmp varchar(25)," +
                        "DireccionEmp varchar(150)," +
                        "ActividadEconomica varchar(300) )";
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Este es el código que uso para crear una tabla

```
public void CrearEmpresa(string nombre)
            {
                using(var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    using(var comando = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comando.Connection = conexion;
                        comando.CommandText = "create database " + nombre;
                        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Intente utilizar la sentencia `USE` para escoger la base de datos recién creada y me agarre la sentencia pero no funciono.
Entonces mi pregunta es, como creo una base de datos con sus tablas desde C# a Sql.

En Obtener conexion esta este codigo

```
public ConexionBD()
        {            
            CadenConexion = "Data Source=DESKTOP-38N3PKP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=basededatos;Integrated Security=True";
        }


        protected SqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(CadenConexion);

        }
```

Comment: que hay en obtener coexion???

Comment: @gbianchi ya edite la pregunta con el codigo de obtener conexion

Comment: claro pero ahi vas siempre a la misma base.. tens que cambiar el Initial Catalog para que apunte a la nueva y el usuario tiene que tener permisos sobre esa base

Comment: @gbianchi y no hay manera que solamente se cree la base de datos? porque yo abro mi aplicación y creo una base de datos, para luego poder ingresar en ella y empezar a meter datos, pero como apunto hacia esa base de datos, al iniciar sesión en mi aplicación?

Comment: esa es tu pregunta real ;)

Comment: @gbianchi ah vale gracias, la edito o se crea una nueva?

Comment: acepta la respuesta que tan amablemente te dieron (que esta bien) y crea una nueva.. si queres pone como referencia esta

Comment: @gbianchi vale gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que crear la base de datos primero.

```
CREATE DATABASE Database_Name
```

Luego le insertas la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
 );
```

Si ya existe la tabla necesitas y necesitas eliminar

```
 DROP TABLE table_name;
```

y la creas.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: si, yo creo la base de datos primero y cuando reviso el Sql me la crea, pero al colocar para crear las tablas, no me agarra la base de datos que acabo de crear

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta situacion usualmente yo uso 2 variantes 
 1. Entity Framework Code First: Permite crear las tablas desde una clase en C#. 
 2. Usando un proyecto SSDT que resuelve el 95% de los problemas con la base de datos y permite tener el codigo sql en git o tfs (Code Control).

**1. Entity Framework Code first.**

1.1 Instalar libreria EntityFramework desde nuget.

```
En Visual Studio
Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console
Ejecuta: `Install-Package EntityFramework`
```

1.2 Crear la clase Empresa.cs

```
public class Empresa
{
  public int IdEmpresa {get; set;}                  
  public string RucEmpresa {get; set;} 
  public string RazonSocialEmp {get; set;} 
  public string NombreComercialEmp {get; set;} 
  public string TelefonoEmp1 {get; set;} 
  public string TelefonoEmp2 {get; set;} 
  public string CorreoEmp {get; set;} 
  public string CiudadEmp {get; set;} 
  public string DireccionEmp {get; set;} 
  public string ActividadEconomica {get; set;} 
}
```

1.3 Crear la clase CompaniaContext.cs

```
public class CompaniaContext: DbContext 
    {
        public CompaniaContext(): base("name=CompaniaDBConnectionString")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }            
    }
```

Uso:

Agregar esto al app.config

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompaniaDBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CompaniaDB -ConnectionString;Integrated Security=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

entonces:

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (var db = new CompaniaContext())
                {
                    db.Empresas.Add(
                         new Empresa { 
                               IdEmpresa = 2,
                               RucEmpresa = "0000020002"

                          });
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    foreach (var emp in db.Empresas)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(emp.RucEmpresa);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Presiona algo para generar una cerveza...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Ahora ejecuta la aplicacion y su base de datos se genera sola, este es el caso mas simple, para utilizar todas las ventajas debe leer sobre Migrations.

**2. SSDT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez creado el proyecto, debe hacer click derecho el el explorador de soluciones en VS y seleccion Importar.
Aqui va a tener que proveer la conexion a su Base de Datos, una vez que la conexion esta establecida usted puede escoger tablas, vistas, triggers, procedimientos almacenados, todo en general. Este proceso temina con su BD creada en Visual Studio, lo demas es regular SQL.

Espero estas ideas le ayuden a resolver su problema.